# Can anyone tell me what's going on here in this Rust struct re: lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
struct MutStr<'a, 'b> {  
  s: &'a mut &'b str 
}
```

I'm scratching my head trying to understand this syntax.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried looking this syntax up everywhere and cannot find anything on two lifetimes on a single struct field.

Comment: What's the problem? It's declaring two lifetimes, and a double reference with the outer reference having lifetime `'a` and the inner `'b`. Nothing special.

Comment: It's a reference to a reference. Each reference has its own lifetime.

Comment: I see.  Thank you.  I thought the & was just syntax needed to define a lifetime for some reason.  I didn't even realize it was a double reference!